# NSImage - can't load image from file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command-line, nsimage

I program **command-line application** that will load image from Supporting Files. Image is copied in Supporting Files, but when I use following code, variable **imgC** returns **nil**.

```
NSString* pathC = @"galaxy.jpg";
NSImage* imgC = [NSImage imageNamed: pathC];
```

**ImgC** returns nil even if I use the following code:

```
NSString* pathC = @"galaxy.jpg";
NSImage* imgC = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: pathC];
```

Can someone please help me?

(PS: Sorry for my bad English.)

Many thanks, Peter

Comment: Are you sure the image is being copied into your bundle?

Comment: Yes. I see image in Supporting Files in Xcode and also in project folder in Finder.

Comment: The `imageNamed:` method only works in an application bundle, you can't use it from a command line tool. And `initWithContentsOfFile:` should be used with an absolute path, not a relative path. Also... you should be using URLs not paths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the target is `commend line tool` since those don't have a bundle `[NSBundle mainBundle]` so its returns `nil`. So You need to used an `absolute path`, not an `relative path`. As this is Strange `Xcode` do't show any kind of warning regarding to this.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Zenga/Documents/iOS/Research/Test/star.png"];
if (image == nil) {
    NSLog(@"image nil");
}
NSLog(@"%f and %f",image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

and i found this path from When i click on the Image and on Right Corner i found this path and i used it and working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: @Sporky Yeah But its Strange as `Xcode` not shows any warning

Answer (score 12):

Swift Style:

```
if let imageRef = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/path/to/galaxy.jpg")
{
    print("image size \(imageRef.size.width):\(imageRef.size.height)")
}
```

Comment: `println`should be replaced with `print(...)`...